# Error trying to use System.Data.SQlite for visual studio

Tags: .net, sqlite, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

Warning 1   The primary reference "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=x86" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". WindowsFormsApplication1

I installed the     sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x64-2013-1.0.94.0.exe 
Im trying to use SQlite to read .db file in C#
When I add reference to System.Data.SQlite I go to 
C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\2013\bin  and select the .dll file

Is there a way to get rid of the problem or am i using something wrong?

ALSO I'M A NEWB SO I REQUEST IF YOU CAN EXPLAIN STEPS IN DETAILS :)

FYI I'm running 4.5.1 .NET Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click your project and click properties, then select Application on the left. The target framework dropdown is what you need to set to 4.5.1

[image]

Comment: Great, please mark as answer if this solved your issue.